# Netsuite: How to enter new line in VAR Suitescript

Tags: suitescript

As per title, I wish to enter new line in var but no clue. Any help?

```
var string  = 'item : 1';
string.replace('1', 'atom 1 \n atom2 \n atom3');
```

I wish to produce an output like

item: 
atom 1

atom 2

atom 3

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out this answer myself.
Will update the answer here in case anyone come into this in future.

```
var string  = 'item : 1';
string.replace('1', 'atom 1  <br> atom2 <br> atom3');
```

Comment: This works for me too. Instead of \n